# Unable to catch web page content with an HTML object from VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba, xml-parsing, html-parsing

Im using this URL https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xtks/1407/dividends
and the table with the upcoming dividends are displayed on my browser
I inspect the page and try to catch the content of the table

I tried this code :

```
    Dim html As New htmlDocument
    Dim HTTP As Object, Elem As Object, Quote As Object
    Dim iTicker As Integer, nTicker As Integer, BBG_Ticker As String, DES As String, TYP As String, MKT_STATUS As String
    Dim vHeader As Variant, vData As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer, t As Integer, k As Integer, nFields As Integer, x As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    
Set HTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
ReDim vWebPxLast(0)

    


        With HTTP
            .Open "GET", URL, True
            .Send
        End With
        
        While HTTP.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        html.Body.innerHTML = HTTP.responseText
        Crash HTTP.responseText
    If HTTP.Status = 200 Then

        Set Elem = html.getElementsByClassName("dividends-recent")
```

but the Elem object is empty

Answer (score 0):

I used selenium with chrome and it worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).